# Type.InvokeMember(..) in CoreCLR

Tags: c#, reflection, dnx, coreclr

I'm trying to dynamically invoke a member on a specific type using CoreCLR, but the method Type.InvokeMember is not available when compiling against DNXCORE50. However, if I compile against DNX451 it works fine.

Below is a sample of how this can be achieved using DNX451, but how can I do the same in DNXCORE50?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace InvokeMember
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            typeof (Program).InvokeMember("DoStuff", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, new Program(), null);
        }

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code, it works :

```
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("DoStuff");
        method.Invoke(new Program(), null);
```

Comment: The original code should work too, if he throws in a `GetTypeInfo()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: GetTypeInfo().InvokeMember does not work.

'TypeInfo' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeMember' and no extension method 'InvokeMember' accepting a first argument of type 'TypeInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) InvokeMember.DNX Core 5.0

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may have been using Type.InvokeMember() with `BindingFlags.SetProperty` to set a property on an object (instead of `BindingFlags.InvokeMethod`), you can use this syntax which is slightly modified from the answer given by @aguetat:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("MyProperty");
property.SetValue(new Program(), newValue);
```